# How to measure water turbidity with arduino

Tags: sensors

I would like to measure water turbidity in the sea. The sensor does not need to measure it in an accurate way, I just need to know if water is clear or very turbided. I know that there could be used a light scatter but I do not know what kind of sensor should I use. Could anyone help how to measure turbidity?

Answer (score 2):

http://uk.farnell.com/ams/tsl257-lf/sensor-light-voltage-converter/dp/1226886
is a good one according to http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=299993.0

But it might be easier to buy a COTS sensor, its a bit more expensive but much easier.  http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Turbidity-Testing-Sensor-Module-Suite/1903197650.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.17.OSVwdj&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_9,searchweb201602_2_10017_9868_10005_10006_10034_10021_507_10022_10020_1000020_10018_10019,searchweb201603_8&btsid=6dbcca61-3e0a-4e34-9359-a6c26b268509

BTW for everyone else Turbidity is the amount of muck in the water, so it would be no good looking at the crystal clear waters off the UK coast :)

Comment: Thanks, do you think that there could be find any datasheet or part number of this chinesse COTS turbidity sensor?

Comment: You could try and ask the seller.  There are quite a few that sell similar units, ask them all and take the average of the responses as closest to the truth.  From the pictures and experience of similar looking sensors you seem to have both an analog and digital connections.  The digital could be in or out, in is usually the signal to make a reading, out is usually just condition sensed / not sensed.
The Sensor looks to be the same as a IR Tachograph sensor, but the receiver board is a bit more complex.  Generally the sellers are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I used an array of cheap light dependent resistors hermetically sealed and used a torch. For dark water, it clearly shows a lower value than for cristal water. It is kind of a binary sensor, but I was proud of my basic invention!